# angular 4 get and load component form an api call

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a way to do the following :

I have a main angular app, I want to load components dynamically and these components will be remote. somehow a plugin system

Is such a thing possible ? Could I get a component from a rest call, like a json ?

thanks for your advice

Answer (score -1):

Try like this :

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    private resourceUrl = 'http://localhost:3002';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getMethod() {
        return this.http.get(resourceUrl)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private appService: AppService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.appService.getMethod()
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data;
            });
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        AppService
    ],
})
```

Comment: Thanks but this is a simple rest call to an api, right ? I would need to retrieve and display a component (template and logic) from a remote. I don't think this is enought

Comment: do you want to display retrieve data in html template use like <div>{{data | json}}</div>

Comment: not at all, I want to get a whole component from a remote service and be able to use it in my main angular app

Comment: do you want your MainComponent calls another SecondComponent?